# How to play mov and wmv video format file in Java Swing?

Tags: java, jmf, mov

I am using JMF jar file, but i am only able to listen the sound but cant view the movie.

```
  Unable to handle format: RLE , 800x600, FrameRate=14.6, Length=31280
  Failed to realize: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@17590db
  Error: Unable to realize com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@17590db
```

some error i got when trying to play the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JMF is <s>basically</s> dead**

You can use **xuggler** to play **wmv** files in java swing.

**[Xuggler is a free open-source library for Java developers to uncompress, manipulate, and compress recorded or live video](http://xuggle.com/)**

[You can view the code here](http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/DecodeAndPlayAudio.java) .

```
package com.xuggle.xuggler.demos;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.demos.VideoImage;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

import com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IStream;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IStreamCoder;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec;


public class DecodeAndPlayAudio
{
  private static SourceDataLine mLine;

 /**
  * Takes a media container (file) as the first argument, opens it,
  * opens up the default audio device on your system, and plays back the audio.
  *  
  * @param args Must contain one string which represents a filename
  */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   if (args.length <= 0)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("must pass in a filename as the first argument");

String filename = args[0];

// Create a Xuggler container object
IContainer container = IContainer.make();

// Open up the container
if (container.open(filename, IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0)
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not open file: " + filename);

// query how many streams the call to open found
int numStreams = container.getNumStreams();

// and iterate through the streams to find the first audio stream
int audioStreamId = -1;
IStreamCoder audioCoder = null;
for(int i = 0; i < numStreams; i++)
{
  // Find the stream object
  IStream stream = container.getStream(i);
  // Get the pre-configured decoder that can decode this stream;
  IStreamCoder coder = stream.getStreamCoder();

  if (coder.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO)
  {
    audioStreamId = i;
    audioCoder = coder;
    break;
  }
}
if (audioStreamId == -1)
  throw new RuntimeException("could not find audio stream in container: "+filename);

/*
 * Now we have found the audio stream in this file.  Let's open up our decoder so it can
 * do work.
 */
if (audioCoder.open() < 0)
  throw new RuntimeException("could not open audio decoder for container: "+filename);

/*
 * And once we have that, we ask the Java Sound System to get itself ready.
 */
openJavaSound(audioCoder);

/*
 * Now, we start walking through the container looking at each packet.
 */
IPacket packet = IPacket.make();
while(container.readNextPacket(packet) >= 0)
{
  /*
   * Now we have a packet, let's see if it belongs to our audio stream
   */
  if (packet.getStreamIndex() == audioStreamId)
  {
    /*
     * We allocate a set of samples with the same number of channels as the
     * coder tells us is in this buffer.
     * 
     * We also pass in a buffer size (1024 in our example), although Xuggler
     * will probably allocate more space than just the 1024 (it's not important why).
     */
    IAudioSamples samples = IAudioSamples.make(1024, audioCoder.getChannels());

    /*
     * A packet can actually contain multiple sets of samples (or frames of samples
     * in audio-decoding speak).  So, we may need to call decode audio multiple
     * times at different offsets in the packet's data.  We capture that here.
     */
    int offset = 0;

    /*
     * Keep going until we've processed all data
     */
    while(offset < packet.getSize())
    {
      int bytesDecoded = audioCoder.decodeAudio(samples, packet, offset);
      if (bytesDecoded < 0)
        throw new RuntimeException("got error decoding audio in: " + filename);
      offset += bytesDecoded;
      /*
       * Some decoder will consume data in a packet, but will not be able to construct
       * a full set of samples yet.  Therefore you should always check if you
       * got a complete set of samples from the decoder
       */
      if (samples.isComplete())
      {
        playJavaSound(samples);
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    /*
     * This packet isn't part of our audio stream, so we just silently drop it.
     */
    do {} while(false);
  }

}
/*
 * Technically since we're exiting anyway, these will be cleaned up by 
 * the garbage collector... but because we're nice people and want
 * to be invited places for Christmas, we're going to show how to clean up.
 */
closeJavaSound();

if (audioCoder != null)
{
  audioCoder.close();
  audioCoder = null;
}
if (container !=null)
{
  container.close();
  container = null;
}
}

private static void openJavaSound(IStreamCoder aAudioCoder)
{
  AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(aAudioCoder.getSampleRate(),
    (int)IAudioSamples.findSampleBitDepth(aAudioCoder.getSampleFormat()),
    aAudioCoder.getChannels(),
    true, /* xuggler defaults to signed 16 bit samples */
    false);
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
try
{
  mLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
  /**
   * if that succeeded, try opening the line.
   */
  mLine.open(audioFormat);
  /**
   * And if that succeed, start the line.
   */
  mLine.start();
}
catch (LineUnavailableException e)
{
  throw new RuntimeException("could not open audio line");
}
```

}

```
 private static void playJavaSound(IAudioSamples aSamples)
 {
 /**
 * We're just going to dump all the samples into the line.
 */
 byte[] rawBytes = aSamples.getData().getByteArray(0, aSamples.getSize());
 mLine.write(rawBytes, 0, aSamples.getSize());
 }

private static void closeJavaSound()
{
 if (mLine != null)
{
  /*
   * Wait for the line to finish playing
   */
  mLine.drain();
  /*
   * Close the line.
   */
  mLine.close();
  mLine=null;
  }
 }
}
```